# Password generator class and CLI

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, c++11

I made a password generator class in C++. I am not as familiar with C++ as I am with C, so I am looking for ways to move to a C++ mindset.

I am also trying to use embedded practices like avoiding allocating memory on the fly and other non-deterministic stuff.

I'll include the source file first, followed by the header, followed by the command line tool that is powered by this class.

**passSingleton.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>     // atoi, rand
#include <iostream>     // cout, endl
#include <random>       // default_random_engine, uniform_int_distribution
#include <time.h>       // time

#include "passSingleton.h"  // class header

passSingleton::passSingleton()
{
    std::default_random_engine generator(time(NULL));
}

passSingleton::passSingleton(unsigned int passLength)
{
    passSingleton();
    setPasswordLength(passLength);
}

void passSingleton::generatePass()
/* Generates an ASCII password */
{
    int i;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(33,126);
    for(i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        password[i] = distribution(generator);  // ASCII chars between 33 - 126
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
}

int passSingleton::generatePass(unsigned int passLen)
{
    if(setPasswordLength(passLen))
        return -1;
    generatePass();
    return 0;
}

char* passSingleton::getPass()
{
    return password;
}

/* Sets password length to a positive int between 1 and MAX_PASS_LEN */
int passSingleton::setPasswordLength(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n < 8  || n > MAX_PASS_LEN) {
        std::cerr << "Password length must be between 8 and " << MAX_PASS_LEN << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    passwordLength = n;
    return 0;
}
```

**passSinglton.h**

```
#ifndef PASS_SINGLE_H
#define PASS_SINGLE_H

#include <random>   // default_random_engine

class passSingleton
{
    public:
        passSingleton();
        passSingleton(unsigned int passLength);
        void generatePass();
        int generatePass(unsigned int passLen);
        char* getPass();
        int setPasswordLength(unsigned int n);
    private:
        static const unsigned int MAX_PASS_LEN = 128;
        char password[MAX_PASS_LEN];
        unsigned int passwordLength;
        std::default_random_engine generator;
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>         // cout, endl, cerr
#include <stdlib.h>         // atoi
#include <unistd.h>         // getopt
#include <fstream>          // ofstream

#include "passSingleton.h"  // passSingleton class

void help();
void version();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* myPass = NULL;
    char* filePath = NULL;
    passSingleton myPassFact;
    int c;
    unsigned int passLen = 8;
    unsigned int qty = 0;
    std::ofstream myFile;

    if (1 == argc) {
        std::cout << "Try `passgen -h' for more information" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Usage: passgen -l PASSWORD_LENGTH" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    /* Get command line options */
    while (-1 != (c = getopt(argc, argv, "hvl:f:q:"))) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        switch (c) {
            case 'h':
                help();
                break;
            case 'l':
                passLen = atoi(optarg);
                if (0 == qty)
                    qty = 1;
                if (myPassFact.generatePass(passLen))
                    return -1;
                break;
            case 'v':
                version();
                break;
            case 'f':
                filePath = optarg;
                break;
            case 'q':
                qty = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case '?':
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }   

    /* Output block */
    if (NULL != filePath) { myFile.open(filePath); }
    while (0 != qty--) {
        myPassFact.generatePass();
        myPass = myPassFact.getPass();
        if (NULL != filePath)
            myFile << myPass << std::endl;
        else {
            std::cout << myPass << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if (NULL != filePath) { myFile.close(); }
    return 0;
}

void help()
{
    std::cout << \
    "Usage: passgen [OPTIONS] \n\
Generates an ASCII password PASSWORD_LENGTH characters long\n\
Example: passgen -l 32\n\
\n\
OPTIONS:\n\
    -l PASSWORD_LENGTH  specifies length of generated password\n\
    -f FILE         outputs password to specified file\n\
    -h          displays this help text\n\
    -v          displays version\n\
    -q QTY          generates QTY passwords" \
    << std::endl;
}

void version()
{

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. It seems like you're a beginner to C++ so you probably want to add [tag:beginner] to the tags. Also, you seem to know some OOP from other languages, feel free to add your background into your question. However, please keep in mind that the code should not get changed, now that a review has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not make this to complicated. Your `passSingleton::generatePass()` method could simply return the password as a `std::string` with the password length as a parameter. Initialization of the random engine should be done from `main.cpp` and could also be passed as a parameter. Remove the class, keep the `generatePass()` method in main.

The check of the password length should generate an exception. If you cannot use exceptions, because of your embedded context, return a `std::optional<std::string>` if you're on C++17 or a `std::tuple<bool, std::string>` where the `bool` indicates success and the `std::string` contains the result.

When compiling, use at least `-Wall` it gives usefull hints on how to improve your code:

```
main.cpp:29:13: warning: unused variable 'this_option_optind'
      [-Wunused-variable]
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
            ^
```

Your application requires a minimum length of 8 characters, but if I run

```
sjank@WSDEBE16040-LXL> ./main -q 3 
!
-
h
```

the length defaults to `1`. Is a minimum length really reasonable? You could give a warning instead. Use a sensible default length and make the `-l` parameter optional.

- prefer `#include <ctime>` over `#include <time.h>`, remove `<iostream>` (see above) and `<stdlib.h>` (use `<cstdlib>` in c++).
- Is writing passwords to a file is required? Is it best practice of storing passwords? Could the user achieve the same functionality otherwise (redirect)?

Answer (score 1):

- Option handling is questionable.

  First, do not hardcode the program name (`passgen`) in the message. Use `argv[0]` (if the executable gets renamed, the original message would lie).

  Second, give help immediately. Forcing the user to invoke the program one more time just to see the help is a nuisance. Consider

  ```
      if (1 == argc) {
          help();
          return 1;
      }
  ```

  Notice `1`. Don't `return 0` on error. Your program could be invoked from the script, and the script should be informed that something undesirable happened.

  Third, it is reasonable to expect that unrelated options could be given in any order. Your code behaves differently depending on the order of `-l` and `-q`. If `-l` is given first, the latter `-q` is ignored.

  Finally, the default case shall tell what option seems wrong, and *also* print the help.
- File handling is scattered. Testing for `NULL != filePath` at three different points gives me shivers. Consider consolidating them either like

  ```
     if (NULL != filePath) {
         myFile.open(filePath, iOS_base::app);
         myFile << myPass << std::endl;
         myFile.close();
     } else {
         std::cout << myPass << std::endl;
     }
  ```

  (there is nothing wrong with opening the file multiple times), or [`freopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/freopen) `stdout`. Don't forget to test the the file has been opened successfully.

  Better yet, always output to `stdout`, and let the user redirect as needed.
- Don't use magic numbers (`33,126`). BTW, why you don't allow a space?
- I understand the desire to avoid dynamic allocation. Just let the client provide the space for password(s).
- C++ is not Java. Don't strive to put everything in a class. I see no reason for `class passSingleton` to exist.

Answer (score 0):

#### I don't know where you are learning `C++` from, but this what you posted is basically `C` with classes.

---

That being said, I am just going to point out in a list what you can improve. You can find enough material on the internet for each of the points.

- Naming

  - Name your classes starting with an uppercase, e.g. `passSingleton` should be `PassSingleton`, otherwise it might look like a function call to the reader.
  - Name your classes, variables, etc. correctly, meaningfully, and written out, e.g. rename `passSingleton` to **`PasswordGenerator`**
  - Naming your generate function `generatePass()` is ambiguous (*pass* could be understood differently) and obsolete. Just name it `generate()` since your class is named `PasswordGenerator`.
- **Use STL containers!!!**

  - instead of `char password[MAX_PASS_LEN]` use `std::string password`. With `std::string` you can still access each character with `operator[]`.
  - You are not using any other containers here, but for future, use `std::vector` instead of raw C arrays.
- In `setPasswordLength()` you are calling `exit(1)` if some requirements are not set. Don't `exit` from a function, rather return a `bool` or `throw`. This way, the caller of the function can still react.
- [**constexpr**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865842/does-static-constexpr-variable-make-sense)

  - you can rewrite `static const unsigned int MAX_PASS_LEN = 128;` to `static constexpr unsigned int MAX_PASS_LEN = 128;`
- just return the generated password in `generate()`. You don't need to save the password since you are not using it anywhere else.
  `auto mypass = myPassFact.generatePass();` Doesn't this look way better?
- In your `passSingleton` constructor, you are creating a local variable `generator` shadowing your member variable. Put the initialization of `generator` into the initializer list of the constructor.
  `passSingleton() : generator(time(nullptr)) {}`
- `nullptr` instead of `NULL`
- consider using [Boost.Program Options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html) instead of manually trying to parse the command line arguments